# Problem with background in link?

Tags: css

I don't whats wrong but I'm trying to put an image as a background to a link, but the image is placed outside the link?! I use this code in the CSS:

```
a.route-bg {
    background: url(../bilder/bilder_ikoner/route1.png) no-repeat left top;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 300px;
}



<div class="box-info">
    <h4>Vilken väg väljer du?</h4>
    <p>
        Ta på dig favoritskorna och kombinera motion med upplevelse och upptäck Köpenhamn till fots utifrån guidens vägförslag.
    </p>
    <a class="route-bg" href="?p=karta&rutt=1">
        <p class="route-links">1. City - Örestad - Sluseholmen - City<br />
           Sträcka ca 00 km<br />
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: This is how the code looks like, the image show up inside the p element

<div class="box-info">
<h4>Vilken väg väljer du?</h4>
<p>
Ta på dig favoritskorna och kombinera motion med upplevelse och upptäck Köpenhamn till fots utifrån guidens vägförslag.
</p>
<a class="route-bg" href="?p=karta&rutt=1">
<p class="route-links">1. City - Örestad - Sluseholmen - City<br />
Sträcka ca 00 km<br />
</p>
</a>
</div>

Comment: add code in your question from your comment.

Comment: I try to paste, but all code don't get inside!?

Comment: When I tried your code. It works fine for me.

Comment: strange!? Still the same problem for me! I get the background link background image just below the headline

Comment: it will be good if you add screen shot of what you are getting.

Comment: I added a image, but I can't see it?

Comment: You need to separate your image text from your code text

Comment: Can you post any more of your CSS?

Comment: That will be to much code, any clue I can search for error?

Comment: It got better when I added left to the link

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the `height` attribute and positioning the background in `left center`.
This works in FF 4

Also. you may want increment `padding-left`.

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGv8p/). I used an image found in google.

The CSS that I use is:

```
a.route-bg{
    background: url("http://www.redsack.com/aastat/Image/arrow_rounded.gif") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 19px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Hope help